# How to build an app that any of the user of this app can create a network and ask other to join

Tags: java, android

i am trying to make an android app which can store multiple user profile and anyone in this profile can create a team and ask other to join the team wirelessly. I am new in android development, that's why i don't know how to start. I need a little bit startup help. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question needs a long answer, but generally i thing you should (after being able to build basic apps) read about 
[Google FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/).

You will probably need to combine the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) with [Users management](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users), maybe with [Cloud Massaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/).

I believe this can be a good place to start.

Best of luck.

Comment: Any demo app And source code references may help me a lot. Do you have any reference?